# How to save tkinter dialog data?

Tags: python, tkinter, dialog, save

I want the user to enter something in the `TextBox`, and if he exits the program and returns to open the program again at any time, he finds that the words he entered are still there.

(Python programmers - Save Dialog- tkinter )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the *state* of the program, you could save it in file, in a database, or put your data in one place and use `pickle`. And at least reload the state on program start.

Comment: I think There is Other Way To Save Data In Dialog Without make a file and restore it .... just write something in text box Or add something to Data grad view and click on button save and give you Message say (Your data saved ... if you Exit from the program and open it again you will found the last thing you write in the program .

Comment: @MohamedElsaeed: There is no other way…the data must be save and restored from somewhere.